How to allow third party cookies in my application?
Some browsers like Safari or Firefox block third party cookies by default.
And Google Chrome posts: https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd?hl=es-419
It means that third party cookies are "insecure" for multiple reasons, idk.
But, I need to enable some third party cookies in my application, use case:
I'm currently developing a web application that connects directly with an instance of GitLab (Self Hosted), every it's fine when I need to consume information from the api (I'm using access tokens)
But, I found a problem, some resources like images, videos, avatars or any multimedia upload are not accesible using the API way.
Following this thread I can understand that it's a limitation from GitLab, but, I encoutered that if my final users haves a current active session in their browser this session can be shared with my application, and it works! but only in Chrome.
So, someone here knows how to prevent blocking of third party cookies? there are some way to indicates to the browsers that I want to allow cookies from specific domains?

Your use case of sharing an existing GitLab session with your application is indistinguishable from user tracking, and that's precisely what third-party cookie blocking is meant to prevent. If it could be circumvented in the way you suggest, it would be pointless. Does GitLab support one of the "privacy preserving solutions" listed in the Google Chrome post?
